# Server file works fine locally, but once deployed (on Heroku), MongoDB returns "false" instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, heroku

When attempting to load JSON data from MongoDb while on the deployed version of the website it returns `false`. There are no issues when doing it locally. Checking `heroku logs` in the CLI tells me that in the issues function (located in issues.js), it "can't read property toArray() of undefined".

There are three main files: **server.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      issues = require('./routes/issues'),
      users = require('./routes/users'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.json());

// routing for issue management
app.get('/issues', issues.getAllIssues);
app.put('/issues/issues.json', issues.putNewIssue);
app.post('/issues/:issue_id.json', issues.postIssueUpdate);
app.delete('/issues/:issue_id.json', issues.deleteIssue);

// routing for user management
app.get('/users', users.getAllUsers);
app.put('/users/users.json', users.putNewUser);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end('<h1>Issue Manager</h2>');
})

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port =='') {
    port = 3000;
}

app.listen(port);
```

... the function from the **routing.js** that produces the "false" results

```
const im = require('issue_manager');

exports.getAllIssues = async (req, res) => {
    let allIssues = await im.issues();
    console.log(allIssues);
    console.log('Operation complete.');
    res.json(allIssues);
}
```

... the module, **issues.js**, that contains the MongoDb client and processes the request

```
'use strict';

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let db, allIssues; 

(async function() {
    const uri = 'censored';
    const dbName = 'IssueManager';
    let client;

    client = MongoClient.connect(uri, 
        { useNewUrlParser: true, 
          useUnifiedTopology: true })
                .then(data => {
                    return data;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return err;
                });

    try {
        db = (await client).db(dbName);
        allIssues = (await db).collection('Issues').find();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();

exports.issues = async () => {
    try {
        return await allIssues
            .toArray()
            .then((data) => {
                return data;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return err;
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs fine in your local environment then I think you should:

1. Confirm that your deployed application can connect to your MongoDB server.
2. If it can't, verify that you are using the right environment variables / credentials in your deployed application.

This is a common mistake we all experience when deploying. =)

Comment: I double checked the env variable for the database URI was accurate. It seems like any time I assign the URI to ```process.env.DB_URI```  it doesn't detect the DB even locally. As for checking if the deployed app can connect, I'm not sure how other than to load it and do the GET request.